# Dependency not found in package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to create a Scraper package to get some data from a website.

I created the package but I cannot access the GuzzleClient from the package.

**The scraper class is very simple:**

```
class Scraper {
    public function get() {
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        
    }
    
}
```

**The Provider:**

```
 public function register()
    {
       
        App::bind('scraper', function()
        {
            return new Scraper;
        });
    }
```

**The declaration in composer.json:**

```
"psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "MyVendor\\myscraper\\" : "packages/myvendor/myscraper/src"
        }
```

*The GuzzleClient is declared in composer.json and installed successfully. I am calling the **scraper** method in a controller.*

*I tried the command `composer dump-autoload` on project root and package root but it didnt work.*

Comment: try  **composer update --no-scripts**

Comment: @BinitGhetiya It didn't help.

Comment: please add laravel, guzzle and mews/captcha into question

Comment: refer laravel forum : http://laravel.io/forum/07-05-2015-class-guzzlehttpclient-not-found-can-not-update?page=1